# A simple free opening editor?

Tags: software

I am looking for a ***simple*** and free opening editor where I can save openings and variations.  I know Chess Position Trainer is free, but I am looking for something much more simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can go here: http://www.caissa.com/chess-tools/pgn-editor.php and select the tab "2. Game Moves", then make your moves. The fourth tab will show the `fen` and the `pgn` of the game.

As far as where to store them, create a folder somewhere named openings, and save each different set of fen/pgn as a text file with the output.

Comment: This is good, but I was looking for something that I can run offline and it would allow me to put in moves in a tree list.